# Derangement, example, paradox?

Tags: permutations, derangements

How can we explain that $!0 =1 $, but $!1=0$?

I understand the case of permutations. I get why $0! =1$, and that $1!$ is also $1$.
This result doesn't argue with my intuition.

But, when it comes to derangements, it's hard to understand for me. Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$0!$ is one, since the number of bijections between $\emptyset$ and $\emptyset$ is $1$. moreover the one bijection that exists does not send any element of $\emptyset$ to itself, so it is also a derrangement and we conclude $!0=1$

The number of bijections from $\{1\}$ to $\{1\}$ is also $1$, so $1!=1$. However this bijection sends $1$ to itself, and therefore is not a derrangement. The number of derrangements on the set $\{1\}$ is therefore $0$, so $!1=0$.